# Get name of the taxonomy name from the term id

Tags: wordpress, categories, advanced-custom-fields, taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I have a custom user registration field call country, outlet, company (They're all taxonomy).

Eg. taxonomy=country&tag_ID=36&post_type=company

```
$country_tagid = the_field('country', 'user_'.$user_id->ID); //This output 36
$countrydata = get_terms('country',array('id'=>$country_tagid)); // 
echo $countrydata->name; //return nothing
$getcountrydata = get_term( $country_tagid );
print ($getcountrydata->name); //return nothing
```

All of them did not return the name. I expect it to return 'Thailand'. What is wrong?

EDIT:
Strange, i manually entered outside the loop of my users.

```
<?php
    $catinfo = get_term_by( 'id', 36, 'country' );
    print $catinfo->slug; //thailand
?>
```

This works.
I suspect something is wrong here

```
$country_tagid = the_field('country', 'user_'.$user_id->ID); //This output 36
```

This line prints 36. Now I'm trying to get_field. but it return me arr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this line is wrong. It did not store the value 36 in the variable. Instead it display it.

```
$country_tagid = the_field('country', 'user_'.$user_id->ID); //This output 36
```

I changed to get_field instead.

```
$country_tagid = get_field('country', 'user_'.$user_id->ID); //This output 36
```

I retrieve the id by

```
$countryid= $country_tagid[0];
```

Then retrieve the country name by:

```
$catinfo = get_term_by( 'id', $countryid, 'country' );
$countryname= $catinfo->name;
```

So the full code:

```
$country_tagid = get_field('country', 'user_'.$user_id->ID);
$countryid= $country_tagid[0];
$catinfo = get_term_by( 'id', $countryid, 'country' );
$countryname= $catinfo->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/

```
$countrydata = get_terms('country',array( 'include' => array( $country_tagid ));
```

//

think your syntax for get_terms is wrong.

Comment: $countrydata = get_terms('country',array( 'include' => array( $country_tagid )));
print_r($countrydata);
It returns  Array ( )